# C# Disambiguation of methods for various fields

Tags: c#, oop

Not sure if the question is precise enough so correct me once you read through the explanation of my problem.

Console application. Simple game. 
So I have 9 fuel pumps and each will be servicing a vehicle. Now - I need refuelling method with timer (or using just plain vars based on the main game timer).

My question is what is the best way to approach it? Either make a separate method for each pump or is there a way to use one method for every single pump (disambiguation of vars etc).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/JFVZHU41

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some of your code or i doubt you will get an answer.

Comment: @CodingYoshi http://pastebin.com/JFVZHU41 Here is a paste of my project. Except Drawing UI class as it is not important. I Know it looks terrific, but I just started learning.

Comment: What is refueling supposed to do? And in plain English would you be able to explain the game?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Refuelling is only setting booleans and reads the player input. Later on I'm planning to add methods for refuelling rules (timers, more boolean and recording the transactions with vehicle Name, Fuel Type and Fuel amount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a broad question so I am just going to give you some idea. You have flagged the question with OOP. If you are asking about "Object Oriented" way of doing it, one of the ways might be to create a class Pump with method refuel. You would then create an instance of class Pump (9 times for each pump). If pumps have different properties like time to refuel, you could make them as public properties. This is just to give you an idea:

```
public class Pump
{
    public int RefuellingTimeSeconds { get; set; }
    public void Refuel(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
       //refuelling code here
    }
}
```

You could then instantiate each pump:

```
var firstPump = new Pump { RefuellingTimeSeconds = 120 };
var secondPump = new Pump { RefuellingTimeSeconds = 90 };
```

The above assumes that all pumps have a same refuelling procedure that only differs with some parameters that can be set from outside.

On the other hand, if you have different types of pumps and only thing they share is the refuelling interface, you could create pump interface that would have different pump implementations:

```
public interface IPump
{
    void Refuel(Vehicle vehicle)
}

public class SlowRefuelPump
{
    public void Refuel(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
       //slow refuelling
    }
}

public class FastRefuelPump
{
    public void Refuel(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
       //fast refuelling
    }
}
```

You could then create pumps as needed and use their interface in your application:

```
var pumps = new List<IPump> { new SlowRefuelPump(), new FastRefuelPump() };
```

and use them as:

```
pumps[0].Refuel(_vehicle);
pumps[1].Refuel(_vehicle);
```

It all depends on your scenario...

Comment: Yea, we were asked to practice OOP as much as wee can + all fields must be private wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you. Could you expand the answer to also include what should be inside the Vehicle class? Im planning to have three different types of vehicles and each of them will use one or more out of three different fuel types. Each generated vehicle will also have a random amount of fuel before fuelling. 

Can you take a look at what I prepared quickly here? Not sure what syntax to use to disambiguate each vehicle that is generated. There won't be more than 10 vehicles at once (9 for each pump and 1 waiting).
http://pastebin.com/BGxydQx9

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class `Pump`, which contains the logic for refueling a `Car` instance.

Each of these pump instances will hold a reference to a car while pumping. The `Pump` class could have a method which increases the fuel in the car based on the game loop.

Something like:

```
public class Pump
{
    private int _fuelRate;
    public Car ServicingCar { get; set; }

    public Pump(int fuelRate = 10)
    {
        _fuelRate = fuelRate;
    }

    public void IncreaseFuel()
    {
        if (ServicingCar == null) return;

        ServicingCar.Fuel += _fuelRate;
    }
}
```

Then initialize your pumps in your game somewhere:

```
var pump1 = new Pump();
var pump2 = new Pump(20); // this one is faster
```

etc...

When you want to fuel a car just assign the `ServicingCar` property.

```
pump1.ServicingCar = car1;
```

You could make some checks whether another car is already fueling etc. That would be a task for you to figure out.

In your game loop you would call `IncreaseFuel` for each of those pumps.

Is this the best way to do it? That is very subjective and hard to answer because of the low detail level of your question. However, this is one simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forget about writing code and programming but try to determine the requirements and put them into simple, plain English sentences firstly. This will help you envision the problem you are solving and come up with a better mental model. Now I don't know your requirements but I will try and make assumptions. For example, here is how you can write the requirements:

1. Create a **game**.
2. The game will consist of **pumps**. The pumps will have numbers assigned to them.
3. The **player** will choose a **pump** by entering a number representing the pump.
4. When a player chooses a **pump**, it will become occupied for a period of time. After which, the pump will be available.
5. To start a pump, a **vehicle** will need to be at the pump.

Based on these requirements, not to get too fancy, using OO concepts, you can just find the nouns and those will become your classes (there are other advanced ways but for start this is really good). All the bolded items are nouns so you will need the following classes:

1. Game (instead of calling it Program, call it Game. This is where the whole thing starts.)
2. Pumps - This will be a list of all pumps
3. Player - the player playing the game. But you may not need this if you are not keeping track of the player and it is assumed only one player is playing.
4. Pump - one individual pump.
5. Vehicle

Let's concentrate on the `Pump` item for now.

Now look at the wording carefully: "a pump will become occupied", this means that our `Pump` class will need a property to store this. "it will become occupied for a period of time", meaning it will also need something to keep track of time. "To start a pump, it will need a vehicle", this means we need a "Start" property but that does not sound right. A property is an attribute and this sounds like an action. Therefore, "Start" should be a method.

For properties always think "adjectives" such as Height, Weight etc. For methods always think "verbs" especially action verbs such as Start, Stop, Walk etc.

**Design**

Ok so let's design the `Pump` class. But before we do that, let's clarify the goals of our design. Our class design should be such that the user of our class can never put the pump in a bad state. For example, if the pump is occupied, we cannot accept another vehicle. The user of the class should not be able to start the pump and provide it a vehicle and also say the pump is free. The pump will need some kind of signal to indicate whether it is free or occupied.

Ok, enough theory, some code now:

```
class Pump
{
    public event EventHandler<PumpEventArgs> StatusChanged;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public Pump(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The name for the pump is not valid. It cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        this.Name = name;

        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this.timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        this.timer.Interval = 100;
        this.timer.AutoReset = true;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the pump is not occupied, we do nothing
        if (!this.IsOccupied)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Looks like the pump was occupied and
        // the timer went off so lets make the pump available by setting the
        // vehicle at this pump to null
        this.Vehicle = null;
    }

    // Private set so the only way to set this is to call the start method
    public Vehicle Vehicle
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vehicle;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.vehicle = value;
            if (value == null)
            {
                this.IsOccupied = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsOccupied = true;
            }

            // If anyone has subscribed to the pump change event, notify them and send them the status
            if (this.StatusChanged != null)
            {
                this.StatusChanged(this, new PumpEventArgs { Status = this.Status });
            }
        }
    }

    // private set so the only way a pump is occupied if start has been called.
    // Other classes should not be able to set IsOccupied to false if there is a vehicle at the 
    // pump.
    public bool IsOccupied { get; private set; }

    // This is a read-only property. It depends on the IsOccupied property.
    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.IsOccupied)
            {
                return "Occupied";
            }

            return "Free";
        }
    }

    public void Start(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        // This object should take care of its own rules. If someone calls Start
        // and the pump is busy and they call start again, do not allow it.
        if (this.IsOccupied)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This pump is already occupied.");
        }

        // Set using property so the property can carry out the other rules
        this.Vehicle = vehicle;

        // Start the pump timer as well
        this.timer.Start();
    }
}
```

If you pay attention, this class has no `Console.WriteLine` or other console references. This class is independent of all that. It is up to the user of the class to decide where to write messages when the pump is available or once it becomes occupied etc. Maybe the user wants to write to console, or maybe the user wants to show a dialog (windows) or maybe the user wants to send a signal to a real light and turn the light green etc. It also, takes care of ensuring that it is always in a good state: if it is occupied, it will not return "Free" for status. Also, it will not allow no one else to set the status to free.

The class also exposes an event when the pump is occupied and when it is free. If the users of the class are interested, they will subscribe to the event and do whatever they need.

So there is the `Pump` class and that should give you many ideas of how to create good classes which are well encapsulated.

Here is the `Vehicle` class but obviously it is not finished.

```
class Vehicle
{

}
```

Here is how the `Game` class but you will need to change it and add more code to it. For example, when a pump is occupied you may need to do something. When it is free you may need to something else. I am simply writing a message to the console.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Pump p1 = new Pump("Pump1");

            // Lets make sure to subscribe to StatusChanged event before you start the pump
            // with a new vehicle.
            p1.StatusChanged += StatusChanged;

            p1.Start(new Vehicle());

            Pump p2 = new Pump("Pump2");
            p2.StatusChanged += StatusChanged;
            p2.Start(new Vehicle());

            //Console.Write("Finished...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    // we can use the same handler for all pumps and we can do different things 
    // depending on who the sender is.
    // Or if you prefer, you can have different event handlers
    private static void StatusChanged(object sender, PumpEventArgs e)
    {
        var pump = sender as Pump;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} status changed to {1}.", pump.Name, e.Status);
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yoshi, you are true samurai of coding. Thank you very much. Currently what Im doing is university project, first year, and Im short on time so I was looking for some help from more experienced guys like you lot. :)